# Javascript : String to a two dimesional Array

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays, string

I have a javascript function which returns a string in the following format :

```
User,5
Group,6
```

I want this string to be converted into a two dimensional array like below, any idea how can I achieve it?

```
[['user,5],['Group',6]]
```

Comment: And [what have you tried ?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I tried str.split(" "); but that returns only one dimensional array.

Comment: i think your result format is wrong. is it `[['user',5], ['Group', 6]]` ?

Comment: Is the result string separated by " " or a new line?

Answer (score 4):

You have to split by line break or blank space and map to split by colon:

```
str.split("\n").map(function(e) { return e.split(',') });
```

EDIT: If you want the second one to be an integer, convert it using parseInt:

```
str.split("\n").map(function(e) {
   var arr = e.split(',');
   arr[1] = parseInt(arr[1], 10);
   return arr;
});
```

Attention, you do have to have [map](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/array_map.htm) installed for browsers that [do not have support for ECMA Script 5](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/) to maintain cross-browser compatibility. You can do that by adding this to your code

```
if (!('map' in Array.prototype)) {
  Array.prototype.map= function(mapper, that /*opt*/) {
    var other= new Array(this.length);
    for (var i= 0, n= this.length; i<n; i++)
        if (i in this)
            other[i]= mapper.call(that, this[i], i, this);
    return other;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var myBigString= "  ";

var str1 =str.split("\n");
var myarr; 
for(var i=0;i<str1.length;i++) {
   var str2 =str.split(",");
      for(var j=0;j<str2.length;j++) {
            myarr[i] = str2[j]
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

USE STRING SPLIT BY COMMA AFTER THAT,FOR EXAMPLE

```
     VAR STR11="User,5";
 VAR STR22="GROUP,6";
    VAR STR=STR11.split(",");
     VAR STR1=STR22.split(",");
    var items = [[STR[0],STR[1]],[STR1[0],STR1[1]]];
```

Comment: note that the second item is still a string, so it is not 5, but "5"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function convert(s) {
  s.split("\n").map(function(s1){
    var splits = s1.split(",")
    splits[1] = parseInt(splits[1])
    return splits
  }
}
```

*assuming your string returned from function to be  `"User,5\nGroup,6"`